# In Spark SQL, how do you register and use a generic UDF?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, udf

In my Project, I want to achieve ADD(`+`) function, but my parameter maybe `LongType`, `DoubleType`, `IntType`. I use `sqlContext.udf.register("add",XXX)`, but I don't know how to write `XXX`, which is to make generic functions.

Comment: I'm curious - why would you write your own implementation of `+`? There's already a plus function, e.g. `df.select(col("a") + col("b"))`

Comment: I'm Sorry,I mean that,for example，parameter of col("a") is IntType,parameter of  col("b") is LongType,parameter of col("c") is DoubleType,Now I want to achieve Add 1,To anyone,I can write sqlContext.udf.register("add",(x:Int or Double or Long) => x+1),but I don't know how to use one funtion to solve all as generic functions.Can you help me ,Thanks

Comment: Well, this can also be done with no new UDF: `df.select(col("a") + lit(1))` would work for any numeric type of column `a` :) but I understand your actual question is about the type issue and how to implement something specific (right?)

Comment: yes,"add+1" is simply describe my problem,In fact,I have this json data like({"score":[1,2,3,4]}),in some time,score's parameter maybe Seq[Long],Seq[Double],Seq[Int],I need to achieve AVG,SUM,MIN,MAX ...function,So,I want to use generic functions to implement ,but to make one again and again, In Scala project,I write OK,but Once I use udf,it's fail,sign!

Answer (score 7):

You can create a generic `UDF` by creating a `StructType` with `struct($"col1", $"col2")` that holds your values and have your `UDF` work off of this. It gets passed into your `UDF` as a `Row` object, so you can do something like this:

```
val multiAdd = udf[Double,Row](r => {
  var n = 0.0
  r.toSeq.foreach(n1 => n = n + (n1 match {
    case l: Long => l.toDouble
    case i: Int => i.toDouble
    case d: Double => d
    case f: Float => f.toDouble
  }))
  n
})

val df = Seq((1.0,2),(3.0,4)).toDF("c1","c2")
df.withColumn("add", multiAdd(struct($"c1", $"c2"))).show
+---+---+---+
| c1| c2|add|
+---+---+---+
|1.0|  2|3.0|
|3.0|  4|7.0|
+---+---+---+
```

You can even do interesting things like take a variable number of columns as input. In fact, our `UDF` defined above already does that:

```
val df = Seq((1, 2L, 3.0f,4.0),(5, 6L, 7.0f,8.0)).toDF("int","long","float","double")

df.printSchema
root
 |-- int: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- long: long (nullable = false)
 |-- float: float (nullable = false)
 |-- double: double (nullable = false)

df.withColumn("add", multiAdd(struct($"int", $"long", $"float", $"double"))).show
+---+----+-----+------+----+
|int|long|float|double| add|
+---+----+-----+------+----+
|  1|   2|  3.0|   4.0|10.0|
|  5|   6|  7.0|   8.0|26.0|
+---+----+-----+------+----+
```

You can even add a hard-coded number into the mix:

```
df.withColumn("add", multiAdd(struct(lit(100), $"int", $"long"))).show
+---+----+-----+------+-----+
|int|long|float|double|  add|
+---+----+-----+------+-----+
|  1|   2|  3.0|   4.0|103.0|
|  5|   6|  7.0|   8.0|111.0|
+---+----+-----+------+-----+
```

If you want to use the `UDF` in SQL syntax, you can do:

```
sqlContext.udf.register("multiAdd", (r: Row) => {
  var n = 0.0
  r.toSeq.foreach(n1 => n = n + (n1 match {
    case l: Long => l.toDouble
    case i: Int => i.toDouble
    case d: Double => d
    case f: Float => f.toDouble
  }))
  n
})
df.registerTempTable("df")

//  Note that 'int' and 'long' are column names
sqlContext.sql("SELECT *, multiAdd(struct(int, long)) as add from df").show
+---+----+-----+------+----+
|int|long|float|double| add|
+---+----+-----+------+----+
|  1|   2|  3.0|   4.0| 3.0|
|  5|   6|  7.0|   8.0|11.0|
+---+----+-----+------+----+
```

This works too:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT *, multiAdd(struct(*)) as add from df").show
+---+----+-----+------+----+
|int|long|float|double| add|
+---+----+-----+------+----+
|  1|   2|  3.0|   4.0|10.0|
|  5|   6|  7.0|   8.0|26.0|
+---+----+-----+------+----+
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can register a generic UDF.

If we take a look at the [signature](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.5.2/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/UDFRegistration.scala#L131) of the `register` method 
(actually, it's just one of the 22 `register` overloads, used for UDFs with *one* argument, the others are equivalent):

```
def register[RT: TypeTag, A1: TypeTag](name: String, func: Function1[A1, RT]): UserDefinedFunction
```

We can see that it's parameterized with a `A1: TypeTag` type - the TypeTag means that at the time of registration, we must have *evidence* of the actual type of the UDF's argument. So - passing a generic function `func` without typing it explicitly can't compile.

For your case, you might be able to take advantage of Spark's ability to cast numeric types automatically - write a UDF for `Double`s only, and you can also apply it to `Int`s (the output would be `Double`, though):

```
sqlContext.udf.register("add", (i: Double) => i + 1)

// creating a table with Double and Int types:
sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq((1.5, 4), (2.2, 5))).registerTempTable("table1")

// applying UDF to both types:
sqlContext.sql("SELECT add(_1), add(_2) FROM table1").show()

// output:
// +---+---+
// |_c0|_c1|
// +---+---+
// |2.5|5.0|
// |3.2|6.0|
// +---+---+
```

Comment: thanks,But if your type is LongType,it's error,says that long is not to cast to double.Now ,I use java.lang.Number,that super class of Double/Long/Int ,implements it.